# Find PACF for die's results sum.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, variance, covariance, correlation

This is [a variation of one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921880/find-pacf-of-sum-on-a-die):

**Problem:**
A die was thrown three times. The results of the throws are $X_1,X_2,X_3$. Let $L = X_1 + X_2$, $S = X_2 + X_3$ and $R = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$.
**Find** $p \Bbb Corr(L,S; R)$.
Note, $p \Bbb Corr(X, Y ;Z)$ means a partial correlation between $X$ and $Y$, "cleared" of the $Z$ effect.

**Trouble**
I came up to two solutions which have different answer.

**My solution $1$**
The idea is here to "offset" the change in **C** by substracting it from **A** and **B**
$$p \Bbb Corr(L,S; R) = p\Bbb Corr(X_1 + X_2, X_2 + X_3; X_1 + X_2 + X_3) = $$ $$ = \Bbb Corr(-X_3, -X_1) = 0 \quad \text{due to independence}$$

**My solution $2$**
I found the following formula on the Internet:
$$ r_{AB|Z} = \frac{ r_{AB} - r_{AC}\cdot r_{BC}}{\sqrt{(1- r^2_{AC})(1- r^2_{BC})}}$$

Using this formula I obtain number $p \Bbb Corr(A,B; C) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

As you can see the results are different. Which approach is wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we clear variables $L$ and $S$ from $R$ such that
$$L = aR + \nu_1, \quad \Bbb Cov(R, \nu_1) = 0$$
$$S = bR + \nu_2, \quad \Bbb Cov(R, \nu_2) = 0$$
than $p \Bbb Corr(L,S; R) =\Bbb Corr(\nu_1, \nu_2) = \Bbb Corr(L - aR, S - bR) = \frac{\Bbb Cov(L - aR, S - bR)}{\sqrt{\Bbb Var(L - aR) \Bbb Var( S - bR)}}$
Now, the task is to find $a$ and $b$.
From condition $\Bbb Cov(R, \nu_1) = 0$ the expression for $a$ follows
$$ a = \frac{ \Bbb Cov(L,R)}{\Bbb Var(R)}$$
Same for $b$.
Using this idea, you should get $a=-\frac{1}{2}$, $b=-1$
The fact that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are from discrete uniform distribution should allow you calculate these covariance and variances easily.
$$p \Bbb Corr(L,S; R) = \frac{2}{3}$$